# Should my server pass along the http status code from a 'nested'/proxy request?

Tags: rest, http, http-status-codes

I have api that hits my server to get data from another site. (I'll use facebook as an example)

When I hit that api endpoint, the server will try to give me back facebook images for my facebook account. If I have not already authorized my facebook account, should I send the 401 status code back to the front end, or handle it on the server and send a 200 with a response that says it failed. (I don't care about the specifics of how to say it failed)

Example:

I click a "get photos from facebook" button.

`mydomain.com/get-facebook-photos/` ---> server fires off to `facebook.com/whatever-the-url-is/` Facebook returns a 401 because I need to sign in.

**What should my response code be from `mydomain.com/get-facebook-photos/`?**

I was thinking it'd be odd for my own endpoint to return a 401 when I'm authorized to hit it, but the next level wasn't.

What is the best practice for this. I'd prefer some type of documentation that lays out the best practice and the why, etc.

Obviously, I have to handle the 401 somewhere, and I thought the best place would be on my server/endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the general answer is to return 502.

However, for this request, 401 makes more sense. Especially if they are not authorizing with your service. There are probably other use cases where it makes sense to return the upstream status code.

Also, if you do return 502, it is helpful to return the upstream status and Warning. These should be returned in the Warning header.

Comment: I like the idea of sending back a 502, but isn't 502 invalid? "not authenticated" is a valid response, right?

Comment: No 502 is Bad Gateway. 401 is a valid response, but the question is, _What is semantic and makes the most sense?_

Comment: 502 is `...received an invalid response from an inbound server it accessed while attempting to fulfill the request.`

Comment: @Jacques, 502 is perfectly valid in that case since the server acts as a proxy. The question here is how you perceive the server. If you want client to told it's just a proxy 502 is ok. Otherwise 401 is a perfect match. 200 is the worst idea - the request did not succeed.